# Changing Intraweb IWFrames at runtime

Tags: delphi, intraweb

I've a simple IntraWeb test project, My Unit1 has an IWform with 3 regions: header, body & footer as below:

```
type
  TIWForm1 = class(TIWAppForm)
    Body_Region: TIWRegion;
    Header_Region: TIWRegion;
    Footer_Region: TIWRegion;
  public
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


initialization
  TIWForm1.SetAsMainForm;

end.
```

My Unit2 and Unit3 are an IWFrame and they have a button only as below:

```
type
  TIWFrame2 = class(TFrame)
    IWFrameRegion: TIWRegion;
    Button1: TButton;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

(**unit3 same as unit2**)

Now, I can assign a frame to the body region easily at design time by dropping Frames form the tool plate to that region.

The problem is how can I change it at runtime to unit3 Frame?

If I try to add it to type section like this

```
type
  TIWForm1 = class(TIWAppForm)
    Body_Region: TIWRegion;
    Header_Region: TIWRegion;
    Footer_Region: TIWRegion;

    MyFram2: TIWFrame2; // added here

    procedure IWAppFormShow(Sender: TObject);
  public
  end;
```

the system tries to remove it!

if I force to keep it to use it as

```
Body_Region.Parent := MyFram2;
```

I got nothing in the body region!

if I add it manually at design time I got the same declaration, I got it working but I cannot change it!

am I missing something here or it is impossible to do so?

btw I'm on Delphi Berlin 10.1 and IW14.1.12.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "removal" of the declared field is not an IntraWeb thing, but a Delphi "feature". Declare it like this, inside a "private" section otherwise it will be treated as published:

```
TIWForm1 = class(TIWAppForm)
  Body_Region: TIWRegion;
  Header_Region: TIWRegion;
  Footer_Region: TIWRegion;
  procedure IWAppFormCreate(Sender: TObject);  // use OnCreate event
private
  FMyFram2: TIWFrame2; // put it inside a "Private" section. 
  FMyFram3: TIWFrame3;
public
end;
```

Remove OnShow event and use OnCreate event instead. Create your frame instances inside the OnCreate event, like this:

```
procedure TIWForm1.IWAppFormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   FMyFram2 := TIWFrame2.Create(Self);  // create the frame
   FMyFram2.Parent := Body_Region;      // set parent
   FMyFram2.IWFrameRegion.Visible := True;  // set its internal region visibility.

   // the same with Frame3, but lets keep it invisible for now  
   FMyFram3 := TIWFrame3.Create(Self);
   FMyFram3.Parent := Body_Region;           
   FMyFram3.IWFrameRegion.Visible := False;

   Self.RenderInvisibleControls := True;  // tell the form to render invisible frames. They won't be visible in the browser until you make them visible
end;
```

Then you can make one visible and the other invisible setting Frame.IWFrameRegion visibility as shown above.